# VBA - enable and disable validation

Tags: vba, excel, validation

I would like to ask is there a way to enable and disable data validation on excel? I would like to disable validation on a certain input,'others'. And enable it if the input is not others.

I had a list data validation, when option `cell== others`, user is able to free text. Else disable free text.

My list validation is done by the excel build in data validation, not using VBA.

This is the code that I have tried:

```
Sub Remove_Data_Validation_Selection()

Selection.Validation.Delete

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Cells(2, 6).Value = "Others" Then
            Selection.Validation.Delete
    Else
           //Enable the validation
    End If
End Sub
```

Right now, when 'Others' is being selected, the validation will be DELETED. How do I enable it back? As `Selection.Validation.Delete` deletes the object, will I be able to enable it back?

Comment: You can do it without VBA in excel. Just apply a formula in "Data Validation" like `=IF(A1="Others",B1=E1:E4,"")`

Comment: @Arul Hi, thanks for the suggestion. The list options is not referring to any cell data. I create the list options directly from the data validation tool, under the "Source".

Comment: Can you try adding your List inside the formula using `OR` like `=IF(A1<>"Others",OR(B1="A",B1="B",B1="C"),LEN(B1)>0)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what I'm looking for, when user chooses other, it will modify the validation setting. You can change the modify to delete if you would like to remove the validation.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$F$2" Then
    If Target.Value = "Others" Then
        With Target.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateInputOnly, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator _
        :=xlBetween
        .IgnoreBlank = False
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
    End
    End If
End If

If Target.Address = "$F$2" Then
  With Target.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="1,2,3,Others"
        .IgnoreBlank = False
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
  End With
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use it in the same procedure, declare object variable

```
Dim Valid As Validation
```

and assign value before deleting. EDIT here.

```
If Cells(2, 6).Value = "Others" Then
        set Valid = Selection.Validation
        Selection.Validation.Delete
```

If you want to set up validation in other procedure:

```
SomeRange.Validation = valid
```

I don't know why you would do it, but this is answer for your question. However, if you want to preserve validation for another procedure, you could do this way:

```
Dim wsHid As Worksheet
Dim rngValid As Range

Set rngValid = Selection
Set wsHid = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
wsHid.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
rngValid.Copy
wsHid.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValidation
```

and then, if you need recreate validation, you just copy it from wsHid.Range("A1") and PasteSpecial Paste: xlPasteValidation. Of course, this is just bunch of ideas, you should adjust it to your code.

Comment: Hi, I don't really get what you mean here. Do you mean that I use VBA to create the List Validation and then just add it back once again? Apologies for my poor english.